# C for loop not working

Tags: c, string, loops, for-loop

```
#include <stdio.h> 
char str[5][10]={"asdasdasd", "", "", "qweqweqwe", "asdasdasd"};

int main (){
change (4, 5, 3, 2);

}


void change (int r1, int c1, int r2, int c2){
int i=0;
for (i=0; i<2; i++){
str[r2][c2+i] = str[r1][c1+i];
}
for (i=0; i<2; i++){
str[r1][c1+i] = ' ';
}
return;
}
```

str is a 2-d string.
when I debug it, the second for loop just Works and deletes those characters, but the first row doesnt work. why?

the error is, when I print the string, the chars at [r1][c1] and [r1][c1+1] is deleted but [r2][c2] and [r2][c2+1] is still empty.

Comment: Gotta love these "Core language feature X not working" questions.

Comment: This line `str[10][5]={"asdasdasd", "", "", "qweqweqwe", "asdasdasd"};` is all kinds of wrong

Comment: what do you recommend to name this quesiton, just in case for other questions? :)

Comment: uupsss, sorry. edited.

Comment: edited again, forgot to use r2

Comment: Still wrong. It's a major type mismatch. Try replacing the string literals like this `"asdasdasd"` => `{'a','s','d','a','s','d','a','s','d','\0'}` and see your problems go away for now. Also `str` needs a complete type... Try to post actual compilable code.

Comment: I still don't get it?

Comment: @user3080477 Please post code that prints the string. The rest seems fine; maybe the printing code is wrong?

Comment: @StoryTeller why dont you help with the question instead of fixing the errors of some random string? my original string will be much bigger than that. this was just an example.

Comment: for (k=0; k<5; k++){  printf ("%s\n", str[k]);   }

Comment: @user3080477 Also, should `str[5][10]=...` be `char str[5][10]=...`? The code is incorrect/misleading the way you have it now.

Comment: I am helping you. Instead of being an ingrate, try to take advice to heart. And if this question doesn't depict your problem, then what the hell do you want?

Comment: guys, my original string is 10x25. I just wanted to write down here a smaller string. that can be wrong.

Comment: sorry, storyteller.. you are right

Comment: printing is fine because when I print the string before this process it is correct.

Comment: I wrote a smaller string because I didn't want you guys to get bored of the details with the original string. the function is the same

Comment: case (r2,c2)=(3,2) : Is displayed correctly.

Comment: It will be because not filled with space as the initial value if the case of r2 = 1 or 2's not appear that you say.

Comment: you mean i should initialize 'char str[5][10]={"asdasdasd", "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", "qweqweqwe", "asdasdasd"}' ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to run that and my outputs for r1 and r2 are

qwdaweqwe

asdas--sd  (two spaces)

and basically it is what the code should be doing.

But if I get your intention right, you want to work with those empty strings. Then you should be feeding your function with different numbers, because array indexing works from 0 to n-1, meaning that if you want to use the second empty string, use index 2. I tried that, but there is problem with the declaration. You can try this

```
char str[5][10] = { "asdasdasd", "         ", "         ", "qweqweqwe", "asdasdasd" };
```

or some fine malloc for those two empty strings. Code above works.