# If-statement won't work

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I am trying to make an iOS-app, where the user answer some questions. The user gets a question, and he is going to range himself on a scale from 1 to 5. When the user have answered 30 questions, a new view will appear, where the user can see how many points he made, and a result-text based on the points.

My problem is, when I use the if-else statement, I always get the result-text for the lowest sum.

```
int intSum = [self.sumFromList intValue];
if (intSum >= 135) {
    NSLog(@"135");
} else if ((intSum >= 120) && (intSum <= 134)) {
    NSLog(@"120 - 134");
} else if ((intSum >= 105) && (intSum <= 119)) {
    NSLog(@"105 - 119");
} else if ((intSum >= 90) && (intSum <= 104)) {
    NSLog(@"90 - 104");
} else if (intSum <= 89) {
    NSLog(@"89 or less");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error");
}
```

Can anyone see what I write wrong, or do anyone knows about any other functions to use? Instead of NSLog I have made two arrays witch generate a result- and range-text (`[self.result objectAtIndex:0];`. Of course the `0` will be changed based on the sum), and different text-colors.

EDIT: This is how I calculate the points: If the user choose two points:

```
- (IBAction)twoPointsButton:(id)sender {
[self addPointsToList:2];
}

- (void)addPointsToList:(NSInteger)points {
questionID = questionID + 1; // Used to get the question from array
questionNo = questionNo + 1; // Used to get question number in title 
listPoints = listPoints + points; // Calculate the points

if (questionID == numberOfQuestions) {
    ResultView *resultView = [[ResultView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ResultView" bundle:nil];
    resultView.sumFromList = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sum: %i",listPoints];

    questionID = 0;
    questionNo = 1;
    listPoints = 0;
    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Spørsmål %i/%i",questionNo,numberOfQuestions];
    self.question.text = [questions objectAtIndex:questionID];

    [self presentViewController:resultView animated:YES completion:nil];

} else {
    self.question.text = [questions objectAtIndex:questionID];
    NSString *newTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Spørsmål %i/%i",questionNo,numberOfQuestions];
    self.title = newTitle;
}
```

}

Comment: What is the value of `intSum` giving you unexpected log output? In other words, there is nothing wrong with the `if` statement. The problem is most likely how you calculate `intSum`.

Comment: These statements [seem to misbehave today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457487/c-for-loop-not-working#comment30566703_20457487).

Comment: @rmaddy $20 that it's integer division... >.<

Comment: Most likely intSum is zero.  NSLog it just before you enter the if ladder.

Comment: Keep in mind that if self.sumFromList is nil, the `intValue` will be zero.

Comment: The problem here isn't the `if` statement.  The problem is your assumption with what's wrong.  First thing I would have done is `NSLog(@"%d", intSum);` before the `if else` blocks.

Comment: And when I couldn't make sense of that, I'd throw a `NSLog(@"%@", self.sumFromList);` just before the first line of the snippet.

Comment: Please remove the redundant conditions from your statements.  If `intSum` is NOT greater than or equal to 135, then you know that it is less than or equal to 134.  You do not need to test it.

Comment: I tried to add a screenshot, but it didn't work... I new view shows the user how many points he gets. If I answer 5 on all thirty questions, the sum will be 150 points.

Comment: We don't need a screenshot.  We need more of your code.  How are you calculating the sum, in code.  Don't tell us in English, tell us in Objective-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your updated code the problem is clear. Your `sumFromList` is a string in the form of `Sum: x` where `x` is the sum.

Why don't you make `sumFromList` an actual `int` property instead of a string. Then you can operate on the number as needed. If you have a need to show the value on the view controller you always have the option to convert the `int` value to a string for display purposes.

By having it as an actual number (instead of a string) you can perform proper checks on the value.

Comment: I haven't seen it before now, and I have to admit that I feel kinda stupid. Of course I can't make a integer out of "Sum: x". Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0):

What is sumFromList?
You're setting the text of sumFromList to "Sum: %i" and later try to get it with intValue.
If it is a label you should use

`[sumFromList.text intValue]`

but this will also give you a value of 0 because the text "Sum: %i" cannot be parsed as an integer.

Answer (score -1):

Branch problems are often a confusion of || when && should be used or && when || should be used. - First try cleaning up your if statement.

If there is still a problem check the variable coming into the loop. A null value coming into the loop always defaults to the lowest branch.

If not null then check to see if the printed value is outside of what your if statement is expecting. Then you have to decide whether to expand your if statement or alter the incoming value to fix your problem.

Try this:

```
int intSum = [self.sumFromList intValue];
NSLog ( @"received intSum = %d", intSum );


if (intSum >= 135) {
    NSLog(@"135");
} else if (intSum >= 120) {
    NSLog(@"120 - 134");
} else if (intSum >= 105) {
    NSLog(@"105 - 119");
} else if (intSum >= 90) {
    NSLog(@"90 - 104");
} else if (intSum <= 89) {
    NSLog(@"89 or less");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error intSum %d", intSum);
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue in any way. While the changes to the `if` statements are appropriate, they are not in any way the problem.

Comment: Putting the NSLog at the top of the if statement checks to be sure the if statement is getting what you think it is getting and will almost certainly fix the problem since that is the likely source of the error.

Comment: How does logging a bad value fix the bad value? If you read the updated question's code and the newer answers you will see the problem. It has nothing to do with the `if` statement. Your answer makes no attempt to solve the problem. The extra conditions in the `if` statement were never the problem.

Comment: The loop has no logic errors, therefore the incoming value must be incorrect. Printing out the value lets you know if it is null or outside the values the loop is expecting. Knowing the value almost always makes the problem obvious. It should be the first thing you try when a branch condition fails.

Comment: Sorry but it is the most complete solution that can be given with the available information in the question. Sometimes that's all someone can give you.

Comment: Editing it to provide a more complete answer - see above